# Scatter array of structures in C MPI

Tags: c, struct, mpi

I have a struct called `Department`, and array of struct Department called `Departments`. I want to scatter this array for the specific number of processes, so that every process has a struct called `Current` containing one element(struct)(Department) from the `Departments` array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

struct Department{
    int position;
    int Department_Destinations[100];
};

struct Department Current,Departments[100];

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int rank, nprocess;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocess);

    if(rank==0){
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        Departments[i].position=i+1;
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
            Departments[i].Department_Destinations[j]=0;
        }
    }

    MPI_Scatter(Departments, sizeof(Current), MPI_BYTE, Current ,sizeof(Current), MPI_BYTE, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose the number of processes is equal to the number of `Departments` elements (Department).

When compile and run this code it gives me this error: "incompatible type for argument 4 of ‘MPI_Scatter’"

Why do I get this error and how to scatter array of structure (Departments) in MPI?

Comment: This is a terrible and very non-portable way to pass structures. Search around the site for questions and answers containing `MPI_Type_create_struct` to find information on how to properly send structures around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MPI_Scatter()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Scatter.3.php) needs a pointer to buffer to scatter and a pointer to the buffer that will receive the message.

If `struct Department Current,Departments[100];`, could you try:

```
MPI_Scatter(Departments, sizeof(Current), MPI_BYTE, &Current ,sizeof(Current), MPI_BYTE, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```